# Retain files after Uninstallation

Tags: installshield-2011

Certains files i am copying from one dir to another dir by using CopyFile command in Installshield 11 Premium. I want to preserve copied files even after uninstallation of product. What are the ways to do so?
-Dev

Comment: Not enough information. Is this an InstallScript or an MSI-based product? Are you calling CopyFile from script code, and if so, from an event or a custom action? Or do you mean the MSI table?

Answer (score 2):

Use Disable(LOGGING)....Enable(LOGGING). Put your copy function between this.

This way, the copy action will not be captured in the log and will not be deleted.